# Rounded rect with transparent background and gradient border

Tags: css, svg

I need to make a rectangle with the following things in mind:

1. transparent white background (80%)
2. gradient border (different colors that come from the backend, 1px wide)
3. can scale according to text length

[image: Like this]

I've tried using SVG and got it working except point 3.

My attempt now is to use 3 svgs (one for the left/right half circle and one for the middle part and position them absolutely but i can't get it to work just yet.

[image]

The middle part shouldn't scale to 100% height but im not familiar enough with svg scaling options.

Im using React and Glamor but that shouldnt matter for this. (snippet doesnt work because of dependencies, but you should get the issue)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { css, style, after } from 'glamor';

const SectionTag = ({ className, name, url, height, borderWidth, fontSize, theme, fillColor }) => {
  const styles = {
    main: {
      padding: 0,
      display: 'block',
    },
    inline: style({
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
    }),
    textWrapper: style({
      position: 'relative'
    }),
    background: style({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      width: '100%',
    }),
    text: css({
      zIndex: 1,
      position: 'relative',
      color: theme.accentColor,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      lineHeight: 1,
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      padding: '8px 1px',
      height,
      margin: 0,
    }),
  };
  return (
    <div className={css(className, styles.main)}>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width={height / 2}
        height={height}
        viewBox={`0 0 ${height / 2} ${height}`}
        className={styles.inline}
      >
        <rect rx={height / 2} ry={height / 2} x={borderWidth / 2} y={borderWidth / 2}
              width={(height * 2) - (borderWidth)}
              height={height - (borderWidth)}
              style={{
                fill: fillColor,
                stroke: `url(#gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()})`,
                strokeWidth: borderWidth
              }} />
      </svg>
      <div className={css(styles.textWrapper, styles.inline)}>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          height={height}
          viewBox={`0 0 ${height - 4} ${height}`}
          className={css(styles.background)}
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
        >
          <linearGradient id={`gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()}`}>
            <stop offset="0" style={{ stopColor: theme.leftColor }} />
            <stop offset="1" style={{ stopColor: theme.rightColor }} />
          </linearGradient>
          <rect
            x={-borderWidth}
            y={0}
            width={height - (borderWidth * 2)}
            height={height - (borderWidth * 2)}
            style={{
              fill: fillColor,
              stroke: `url(#gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()})`,
              strokeWidth: borderWidth,
              vectorEffect: 'non-scaling-stroke',
              height: height,
              top: 0,
              padding: 0,
              margin: 0,
            }} />
        </svg>
        <p
          height={height}
          className={css(styles.text, styles.inline)}
        >
          {name}
        </p>
      </div>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width={height / 2}
        height={height}
        viewBox={`0 0 ${height / 2} ${height}`}
        className={styles.inline}
      >
        <rect rx={height / 2} ry={height / 2} x={-(height * 1.5)} y={borderWidth / 2}
              width={(height * 2) - (borderWidth)}
              height={height - (borderWidth)}
              style={{
                fill: fillColor,
                stroke: `url(#gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()})`,
                strokeWidth: borderWidth
              }} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

SectionTag.propTypes = {};
SectionTag.defaultProps = {
  name: 'default',
  height: 29,
  borderWidth: 1,
  fontSize: 10,
  fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)',
  theme: {
    leftColor: 'rgba(255, 188, 0, 0.31)',
    rightColor: '#ff0000',
    accentColor: '#f9811b'
  }
};

const mountNode = document.querySelector('.el');
ReactDOM.render(<SectionTag name="Jane" />, mountNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The positioning of the middle part of the gradient was a bit tricky but here's my code:
[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { css, style } from 'glamor';

const SectionTag = ({ className, name, url, height, borderWidth, fontSize, theme, fillColor }) => {
  const styles = {
    main: {
      padding: 0,
      display: 'block',
    },
    inline: style({
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
    }),
    textWrapper: style({
      position: 'relative',
      height,
    }),
    background: style({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      zIndex: 0,
    }),
    text: css({
      zIndex: 2,
      position: 'relative',
      color: theme.accentColor,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      lineHeight: 1,
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      padding: `${(height - fontSize)/2}px 1px`,
      margin: 0,
    }),
  };
  return (
    <div className={css(className, styles.main)}>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width={height / 2}
        height={height}
        viewBox={`0 0 ${height / 2} ${height}`}
        className={styles.inline}
      >
        <rect rx={height / 2} ry={height / 2} x={borderWidth / 2} y={borderWidth / 2}
              width={(height * 2) - (borderWidth)}
              height={height - (borderWidth)}
              style={{
                fill: fillColor,
                stroke: `url(#gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()})`,
                strokeWidth: borderWidth,
                vectorEffect: 'non-scaling-stroke',
              }} />
      </svg>
      <div className={css(styles.textWrapper, styles.inline)}>
        <p
          height={height}
          className={css(styles.text, styles.inline)}
        >
          {name}
        </p>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          height={height}
          width="100%"
          className={css(styles.background)}
        >
          <linearGradient id={`gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()}`}>
            <stop offset="0" style={{ stopColor: theme.leftColor }} />
            <stop offset="1" style={{ stopColor: theme.rightColor }} />
          </linearGradient>
          <rect
            x={-height}
            y={borderWidth/2}
            height={height- (borderWidth)}
            style={{
              width: `calc(100% + ${height * 2}px)`,
              fill: fillColor,
              stroke: `url(#gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()})`,
              strokeWidth: borderWidth,
              vectorEffect: 'non-scaling-stroke',
            }} />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width={height / 2}
        height={height}
        viewBox={`0 0 ${height / 2} ${height}`}
        className={styles.inline}
      >
        <rect rx={height / 2} ry={height / 2} x={-(height * 1.5)} y={borderWidth / 2}
              width={(height * 2) - (borderWidth)}
              height={height - (borderWidth)}
              style={{
                fill: fillColor,
                stroke: `url(#gradient-${name.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()})`,
                strokeWidth: borderWidth
              }} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

SectionTag.propTypes = {};
SectionTag.defaultProps = {
  name: 'default',
  height: 29,
  borderWidth: 1,
  fontSize: 10,
  fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)',
  theme: {
    leftColor: '#73abff',
    rightColor: '#ff8c2b',
    accentColor: '#0000FF'
  }
};

export default SectionTag;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    border-right: 3px solid blue;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    font-size:24px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 1px;
    height: 2px;
   right:1px;
    display:block;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    height: 2px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>Submit</div>
```

Comment: That wont work, gradient needs to start in the border

Answer (score 0):

You can add SVG like this.

```css
/* just styles for demo */
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 105 105" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0070d8" />
      <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#2cdbf1" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#83eb8a" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g transform="ref(svg, 0, 0)">
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="100" height="100" rx="20" ry="20" fill="none" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-width="0.5" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

So examples using this SVG. Note: example works only in Chrome, use external SVG (recommended way) or escape SVG markup for this work in all browsers:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 5%;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 105 105" preserveAspectRatio="none"><defs><linearGradient id="gradient"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0070d8" /><stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#2cdbf1" /><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#83eb8a" /></linearGradient></defs><g transform="ref(svg, 0, 0)"><rect x="2" y="2" width="100" height="100" rx="20" ry="50" fill="none" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-width="0.5" /></g></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is div
</div>

<div>
  This is also div with very long text.
</div>

<div>
  This is also div with very long text. This is also div with very long text. This is also div with very long text.
</div>

<div>
  This is also div with very long text. This is also div with very long text.<br /> This is also div with very long text.
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this example! I just need the border-radius to be consistent so this method wont work. Check my own answer for my (working) solution.